# how can I use multi functions in one page without change the URL using Django?

Tags: python, html, django, yt-dlp

I'm trying to use Django to build my yt-dlp app, I want to create one page with had toggle list or multi buttons, when I use the first action on the toggle list or button the yt-dlp will download the video file or best quality the video, and when I use the second action the yt-dlp will download the audio file, I tried this

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL

def hq(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        URLS = request.POST['HQ'] # to input a url by the user
        opt = {
            'format' : 'bestvideo/best'
        }
        with YoutubeDL(opt) as ydl: # with used to put ydl_opts and apply changes
            ydl.download(URLS) # to start downloading 

        # print('Successfully downloaded')
    return render(request, 'video.html')
# Create your views here.

def ad(request):
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        URLS = request.POST['audio'] # to input a url by the user
        opt = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        }
        with YoutubeDL(opt) as ydl: # with used to put ydl_opts and apply changes
            ydl.download(URLS) # to start downloading 

        # print('Successfully downloaded')
    return render(request, 'audio.html')
# Create your views here.

def list(request):
    return render(request, 'list.html')
```

---

```
#list.html 
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} 

list

{% endblock title %}



{% block body %}

<ul class="nav justify-content-center">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/audio"> audio </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/ydl">video</a>
    </li>
</ul>

{% endblock body %}
```

---

```
#audio.html 
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
audio only 
{% endblock title %}


{% block body%}

<h1 class="display-1"> audio only </h1>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" id="button-addon1">Button</button>
    <input type="text" name="audio" class="form-control" placeholder="audio only" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
</div>

</form>
{% endblock body %}
```

---

```
#video.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} 

best hq only 

{% endblock title %}


{% block body %}

<h1 class="display-1"> best hq only </h1>

<br>

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

<div class="input-group mb-3">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" id="button-addon1">Button</button>
    <input type="text" name="HQ" class="form-control" placeholder="BEST HQ" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock body %}
```

---

so how can I use the functions in one page?

Comment: Have you tried to put the desired functions into a single page and function?

Comment: @monkut I tried to put html lines in one page but it will separate or it will have error, if you know how help me, I'm trying to make MeTube but with myself

Comment: what's the error?